# How to convert column declared in database as varchar to time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time

I have data in a database column declared as `varchar` like this:

```
08.30
4    
8.3  
3    
5    
9    
3    
3
```

This should be read as 8 hour 30 min, 4 hour and so on.

And I want to convert it into time in SQL Server

Comment: Is the third line `8.3` the same as the first one - 8 hours 30 minutes? Or is it 8 hours, 3 minutes? Or is it really 8.3 (fractional value) hours ?? This representation is very unclear and very much up for interpretation.......

Comment: @marc_s it is same as 8 hour 30 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timefromparts()` in concert with `parsename()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('08.30')
,('4')
,('8.3')
,('3')
,('5')
,('9')
,('3')
,('3')
 
Select SomeCol
      ,AsTime = TIMEFROMPARTS(floor(try_convert(decimal(10,2),SomeCol))
                             ,parsename(try_convert(decimal(10,2),SomeCol),1)
                             ,0,0,0)
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol AsTime
08.30   08:30:00
4       04:00:00
8.3     08:03:00
3       03:00:00
5       05:00:00
9       09:00:00
3       03:00:00
3       03:00:00
```

**EDIT**

The datatype TIME will not support 24+ hours

If you just want to reformat the string  ie `33.3`  to `33:30`

```
Select SomeCol
      ,AsTime = replace(left(try_convert(decimal(10,2),SomeCol),10),'.',':')
 From  @YourTable A
```

Comment: its working fine for some value but showing error (Cannot construct data type time, some of the aguments have values which are not valid. ) may be not working for time above 24hr i.e 28, 33.3 etc

Comment: @firozkhan Time will not support 24+ hours.  See EDIT to see a simple reformat

Comment: and also i want to sum all as total it tried Select SomeCol
      ,AsTime = sum(replace(left(try_convert(decimal(10,2),SomeCol),10),'.',':'))
 From  @YourTable A but it showing error Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, but it's far from pretty. Hopefully the reason for you're doing this exercise is to fix your design:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,ISNULL(CONVERT(int,P.Hours),0),DATEADD(MINUTE,ISNULL(CONVERT(int,LEFT(P.Minutes+'00',2)),0),CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00')))
FROM (VALUES('08.30'),
            ('4'),
            ('8.3'),
            ('3'),
            ('5'),
            ('9'),
            ('3'),
            ('3'))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',V.YourColumn)))CI(I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(ISNULL(LEFT(V.YourColumn,NULLIF(CI.I,0)-1),V.YourColumn),STUFF(V.YourColumn,1,NULLIF(CI.I,0),'')))P(Hours,Minutes);
```